# Proper "Angular" way to pass behavior to directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

When looking for information regarding Angular directives and passing behavior to directives, I get ended up being pointed in the direction of method binding on an isolate scope, i.e.

```
scope: {
  something: '&'
}
```

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) for this functionality is a bit confusing, and I don't think it'll end up doing what I want.

I ended up coming up with this snippet (simplified for brevity), that works by passing a scope function in `HomeCtrl`, and the directive does it's work and calls the function. (Just incase it matters, the real code passes back a promise from the directive).

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
  .directive('passingFunction',
    function() {
      var changeFn,
        bump = function() {
          console.log('bump() called');
          internalValue++;
          (changeFn || Function.prototype)(internalValue);
        },
        internalValue = 42;

      return {
        template: '<button ng-click="bump()">Click me!</button>',
        scope: {
          onChange: '<'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          if (angular.isFunction(scope.onChange)) {
            changeFn = scope.onChange;
          }

          scope.bump = bump;
        }
      };
    })
  .controller('HomeCtrl',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.receive = function(value) {
        console.log('receive() called');
        $scope.receivedData = value;
      };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
  <passing-function on-change="receive"></passing-function>
  <p>Data from directive: {{receivedData}}</p>
</div>
```

Is this a proper "Angular" way of achieving this? This seems to work.

Comment: do you want to fire in the controller a custom function set by the html, but triggered by the directive ng-click ? Why don't you use events and let the controller resolve the execution of the function ?

Comment: I need the directive to be able to call a arbitrary function. The real directive is intended to wrap a search functionality, containing functionality to accept user input, call a search server, and get results, but the only thing I want the controller caring about is results from the search. Ultimately, I'm attempting to pass the search results (in the simplified example above, the 'internalValue') to the controller. Regarding why not use events, that's really the reason for the question... if there's a better way I'd rather use that better way.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to pass the function to the directive.  I'll make a very small example.

On controller:

```
$scope.thisFn = thisFn(data) { console.log(data); };
```

In html:

```
<my-directive passed-fn="thisFn()"></my-directive>
```

On directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', [
  () => {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        passFn: '&'
      },
      template: '<div id="myDiv" ng-click="passFn(data)"></div>',
      link: (scope) => { 
          scope.data = "test";
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Comment: I've been able to get that far, but how then do I call `passedFn()` passing in an object that in the scope of the directive's factory function?

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% know what you mean, but I've updated my code to reflect what I *think* you mean.